# Searching for words in a random string of text

Tags: string, performance, search

I am looking for an efficient way to find words in a random string of text. The possible words to find are from a large word list. Words found within words should not be counted (e.g. "xxxxcatchxxxx" should find "catch" instead of "cat".).

Comment: You might need to do negative lookahead regular expressions, _e.g._ `cat(?!ch)` .

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use 'in'.

For instance:

```
if "catch" in "xxxxxxcatchxxxxxx":
    pass
```

Comment: I could  do something like that with every word in the word list, but that would still give me false positives of smaller words.

Comment: this is somewhat vague... if you have xxxxcatstarxxxxx do you want 'cats' and 'tar' or 'cat' and 'star'? Specifics would be helpful.